# VB6 API Declaration Path

Tags: api, vb6, zlib

I have the following declaration in a Module:

```
Private Declare Function gzopen Lib "ZLIB.DLL" (ByVal filePath As String, ByVal mode As String) As Long
```

The following code line in a function fails, with a 'File Not Found: ZLIB.DLL' error:

```
lGZFileHandle = gzopen(sPath, "rb")
```

I'm aware that ZLIB doesn't need to be registered.  My question is, where does ZLIB.DLL need to live in order for my code to work?  I also know that this code *is* working on another machine.  Currently I have ZLIB.DLL in the same folder as the application exe.

**UPDATE**

To my relief, the code does work when compiled.  But does not work whilst running in the IDE (it does on a different machine).  I still have ZLIB.DLL in the application folder.
This means that the application path must be being checked for loading the DLL.

To get around this I have tried:

```
Private Declare Function SetDllDirectory Lib "Kernel32" Alias "SetDllDirectoryA" (ByVal path As String) As Long
```

and then in the function:

```
SetDllDirectory App.path
```

This seems to allow the DLL to load, but I then get a 'Bad DLL calling convention' error instead.  The plot thickens.

**SOLVED**

The answer seems to be here: http://www.zlib.net/DLL_FAQ.txt. It's a case of RTFM I suppose. 
So, bizzarely whilst in the IDE, the `STD_CALL` convention is in force, but once compiled the C style calling convention suffices. It still doesn't explain why it works on a different machine in the IDE. Ho hum.

Thanks all for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Just put the dll in the system folder already!

Comment: I did already, get the above error. But I have the answer.

Comment: VB6 always uses STD_CALL, it does **not** use C conventions when in the IDE. It's more likely that you have two versions of ZLIB.DLL on your machine, a STD_CALL one built with the ZLIB_WINAPI macro defined and a standard C convention one. Or, possibly, you changed the `Declare` to use ZLIBI.DLL when you compiled, and in the IDE when it failed to find the DLL in the VBP directory you then changed it back to try to fix the problem?

Comment: You are quite right MarkJ.  I had a version of ZLIB in the Windows/System32 folder which was compatible with VB, hence it 'magically' worked on this machine.  Still it remains, that the C style ZLIB worked after compiling the VB project.

Comment: On a `cdecl` call the stack gets corrupted but VB6 tries to repair the damage and it seems to work. Obviously p-code (in IDE) is not so lucky with stack repair. You can use `cdecl` calling thunks to make it work w/o corrupting stack (http://planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=49776&lngWId=1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VB6 strayed a bit from the search protocol suggested by Ken (this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586%28VS.85%29.aspx) is the quick reference).

The usual problem is that the .exe path (search location #1 on the list) is *not* the path of your VB program, but rather the VB6 IDE. So putting the DLL in the location of your VB program is no good -- unless you change the 'Start In' location of your VB6 shortcut to point to that location.

Alternately, you can put the DLL in one of the other locations specified in my link.

Comment: Another workaround is to always change the working directory before calling the DLL. I forget the VB6 statements, I think it's ChDrive and ChDir

Answer (score 2):

When running through the Visual Studio IDE, all relative files need to be placed in the following folder:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98\

This is because the exe that is running while debugging resides in that folder. This will allow you to debug without changing any paths.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure ZLIB doesn't have to be registered?

I suggest you register it and try again.

**EDIT**
Try putting the DLL in your System folder.  I believe your program will check there for it.

Comment: Quite sure. If I try Regsvr32 then I get a 'This file cannot be registered' error.

Comment: DLLs directly referenced by the DECLARE statement do not need to be registered.

Answer (score 0):

ZLib has to be in the standard DLL load search path. See the [MSDN LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175(VS.85).aspx) documentation for specifics on the way DLLs are found and the order of the search for them.